# SQL Server Multiple Assignments within IF or CASE WHEN block

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, select, case-when

I was wondering if it's possible to assign values to multiple fields within a block of an IF or CASE WHEN statement in SQL Server 2008? In a project I am working on, when a condition is met, I want to assign specific values to 4 different fields, if not met I want to assign other values to the sames fields.
See examples below.
Thanks in advance for your help. Any tip will be welcome.

[SELECT With CASE WHEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKwaX.jpg)

[SELECT with IF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5n0y.jpg)

```
SELECT  Field1
        ,Field2
        ,Field3
        CASE 
        WHEN Condtion1_Met THEN
           ,Field4 = Value4A
           ,Field5 = Value5A
           ,Field6 = Value6A
           ,Field7 = Value7A
       ELSE
           ,Field4 = Value4B
           ,Field5 = Value5B
           ,Field6 = Value6B
           ,Field7 = Value7B
       END
FROM Table1
______________________________________________

SELECT  Field1
       ,Field2
       ,Field3
       IF Condtion1_Met
          BEGIN 
             ,Field4 = Value4A
             ,Field5 = Value5A
             ,Field6 = Value6A
             ,Field7 = Value7A
          END
       ELSE
          BEGIN
             ,Field4 = Value4B
             ,Field5 = Value5B
             ,Field6 = Value6B
             ,Field7 = Value7B
          END

FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible.   A `CASE` expression (it is considered to be an expression, not a statement) can only return a single value.   It can't set multiple values.

And an `IF` statement can't be used inside a query at all.   Instead you could do this:

```
IF Condition1_Met
 SELECT ...
ELSE
 SELECT ...
```

Comment: Is it the same if I use IF?

Comment: I should have specified, it is in a stored procedure. I have used IF before and it worked but not for multiple assigments.

Comment: It doesn't matter that it's in a stored procedure.  You can use `IF` to control flow, but you can't use it inside a SELECT query, or any other query for that matter.   Now if you have `SQL Server 2012` or higher, and you're actually talking about `IIF()`, then that expression has the exact same restrictions as `CASE`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided to use a WHILE loop combined with IF/ELSE statements to UPDATE the fields in the table.